# Chance that a group of 5 from 10 people will contain two friends

Tags: probability, combinatorics, solution-verification, combinations

So the problem is to divide 10 people into 2 groups of 5 and find the chance that 2 friends are in the same group. Is it too simple to say:

Let Person A be in a group. Then the chance that Person B is also in that group is 4/9, since there are 4 other possible spaces in that group that can be filled by the 9 remaining people.

Is there a combinatorial way to prove this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your solution is optimal.  However, if you really want to see a combinatorial solution, keep reading.

There are $\binom{9}{4}$ to select the other four members of the group containing person $A$.  If person $A$ and person $B$ are in the same group, there are $\binom{8}{3}$ ways to select the other three members of their group.  Hence, the probability that person $A$ and person $B$ are in the same group is
$$\frac{\dbinom{8}{3}}{\dbinom{9}{4}} = \frac{4}{9}$$
which you found by using a simpler method.

Answer (score 1):

We can think like there are two groups such as group $A$ and group $B$

Lets say that they both are in group $A$ ,then the the probability of being $A$ can be calculated $\frac{C(8,3) }{C(10,5)} \times \frac {C(5,5) }{C(5,5)}=\frac{2}{9}$ .However ,
they might have been in group $B$ , so we should multiply by $2$ .Hence , the result is $\frac{4}{9}$